# AVD not appearing

Tags: android, mobile, android-virtual-device

Whenever I'm starting an AVD, the loading prompt flashes then disappears quickly. [Image of loading infintely after prompt disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAc2H.png)

Possible solutions I found and tried so far

1. I already restart IDE, AVD and unit itself
2. Already create a lot AVDs with different OS
3. Already change Emulated Performance > Graphics > Software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem but this will only work if you are using **Windows 10 Pro N.**

After trying one solution of using **cmd**:
`~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -avd {DeviceName}`

An error appears saying: `Mfplat.dll is missing`...

---

After looking up what it means, I found out that it only occurs because I'm using **Windows 10 Pro N**

So I downloaded `Media Feature Pack` in

> Settings > Apps > Apps & Features > Optional Features > Add a feature

A restart is required and after that, just use that **cmd** again

I hope this will fix yours